# Trying to get the directory name from a users choice array

Tags: bash

I built this array to list a directory's contents that would allow the user to input a number instead of the exact directory name. I do not know how I can get the picked directory's name from the input which is only a number? I need it to identify what exact directory was picked from the array that will be used. Thanks to all those willing to help.

```
if [ -d $TDDIR ]; then
# List folders in $TDDIR
VAR1=1
FILES=( `ls $TDDIR` )
FILECNT=${#FILES[*]}
# List number of folders available
clear
echo "Current list of folders to pick from."
echo
while [ $VAR1 -lt $FILECNT ]; do 
    echo -e "[$VAR1] \t ${FILES[VAR1]}"
    let "VAR1 += 1"
done
# Reduce VAR1 by one
let "VAR1 -= 1" 
# Have user choose which to use for scan
read -p "Which file would you like to scan 1 - $VAR1 or 0 to exit? :" INPUT
  if [ $INPUT -eq '0' ]; then 
    echo "You chose to quit. Exiting now." 
    sleep 2
    exit 0
  fi
while (( $INPUT > $FILECNT || $INPUT < 1 || $INPUT > $VAR1 )); do
echo
echo "You selected $INPUT."
read -p "$INPUT is not valid.  Choose a valid option: " INPUT
done
else    exit
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo ${FILES[(($VAR - 1))]}
```

The -1 is because the index for bash arrays starts from 0.

A side note, ls is not appropriate for the task (see: [Parsing ls output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)s)

Also, you may try using select for the menu (see: [Bash Script Menus and Functions](http://grover.open2space.com/content/bash-script-menus-and-functions))

Comment: Thanks for the help I will try those options, but could I cat or printf the output of the array and get the directory name from there and then -cut it out?

Comment: I don't understand your question, the first line of this answer gives you the solution